How to find device usage data (Windows 11 - Powershell)
We are looking at reducing our fleet of computers and want to know how long a device is being actively used for (i.e. once the user logs in - MINUS all the time that the screen was locked or had a screensaver). So if a user was logged on let's say, 11:00 AM on 10th August and then walked away from the device on 12:00 PM on 10th August, usage data should show 1 hour for 10th August.
I have tried looking at event IDs, GetLastInputInfo. Been out of scripting game for a while, and can't even conceptually figure out, what approach should I take.

I assume you do not have the event logs for the lifetime of the device?

Yes we are capturing event logs. They go back a couple of months, which would be okay for us.

You out these logs into a log server to parse or you simply have them in the system itself?

Have them in the system. But can parse it into a server. Just trying to find out if someone has solved this problem before and how to go about it.
